# Lenovo Thinkpad HDD Error While Running Recovery Tool - Windows 7 OS

Tags: windows-7, thinkpad, hard-drive-failure

My Lenovo T430 started to "hang" or shut-down unexpectedly.  Norton's did not find any viruses, but when running the Lenovo hardware tests (included with the system), a HDD failure was identified.  I then interrupted the system boot-up to allow me to run the HDD recovery tool.  During the test, 8 bad sectors were identified.  Also, the test results included an error message "ERROR DIFFERENT OF UNC" and "CANNOT CONTINUE TESTING. ERROR TIME-OUT".

I then ran the Recovery tool and allowed the 8 sectors to be fixed - which appeared to be successful.  Unfortunately, the "ERROR DIFFERENT OF UNC" and "CANNOT CONTINUE TESTING. ERROR TIME-OUT" messages remain - the HDD testing stopped at ~30% of the test completion.

I use this system for my work - is there a fix that can be made to correct the problem, without getting a new HDD?  The system is currently running (I am using it now) - I have no idea how severe the problem is nor whether the system will be stable (since I did fix the 8 bad sectors).  I would really appreciate any help that can be provided.

Oh yes - my 3 year warranty on the system ran out 5 months ago.

Comment: Back up your data **now**. Once a hard disk drive starts going wrong, it tends to fail completely soon after (hours, days, weeks). If those bad sectors had been one-at-a-time over a few months then the drive would have automatically reassigned those sectors. To find eight in one go is not good. You should assume that the drive will fail completely without warning - it really needs a new HDD for your peace of mind.